# Do I have to reload RevMob Ads?

Tags: ios, ads, revmob

I want to use both fullscreen and banner ads in one of my games. Do I have to load the fullscreen ad everytime before showing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you don't call the SDK will call it for you.

But if you load some time earlier than you need to show, it will be much more faster to show it.

Comment: Ok, so, I'm pre-loading the full screen ad, then I show the pre-loaded ad. 

The next time that I show the ad do I have to get rid of my old pre-loaded full screen ad object and create a new object and load it again and then show? or can I just re-show the old-ad?

Comment: I just tested it here. I pre-loaded and fullscreen ad and then presented it over and over again, the same ad came up everytime. I guess I have to create and pre-load the fullscreen ad everytime I want to show one…

Comment: If the user didn't clicked on the ad there is no necessity to load another one, but you are correct it will show the same creative.

Comment: Ok. Thats what I needed to know. I want to load a new ad everytime I show it because I don't wanna show the same ad over and over again ;)
Valeu diogot!